# With CSS how can I make it so a scroll bar appears to access divs that disappear upon window resizing?

Tags: html, css

I think this is probably a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I can't get overflow: scroll or overflow: auto to work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #container
        {
        }

        #leftDiv
        {
            background-color: #DA4747;
            display: in-line;
            height: 500px;
            left: 200px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            width: 400px;

        }

        #rightDiv
        {
            background-color: #DA4747;
            display: in-line;
            height: 500px;
            left: 800px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="leftDiv">
            </div>
            <div id="rightDiv">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

Comment: I think your problem is in the `position: fixed` - overflow doesn't work with elements positioned with fixed or absolute.

Comment: `display: in-line;` should be `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` wont work, try `position: absolute;`

fixed would make no sence anyway because it keeps the position on the browser.

absoulte keeps the position according to its parent element.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8nsF/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftDiv"></div>
    <div id="rightDiv"></div>
</div>


#container {
    overflow: auto;
}
#leftDiv {
    background-color: #DA4747;
    display: in-line;
    height: 500px;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
#rightDiv {
    background-color: #DA4747;
    display: in-line;
    height: 500px;
    left: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
```